# how to build the plaintext structure for impossible differential cryptanaysis on IDEA?

Tags: cryptanalysis, differential-analysis, idea

I'm trying to implement impossible differential cryptanalysis on 3.5 round IDEA using [Miss in the Middle Attack on IDEA and Khufu](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48519-8_10) paper as a reference and I'm stuck on the first two steps of the attack:

[image]

In the paper the authors say that I should choose a structure of $2^{32}$ plaintexts $X^1$ with identical $X^1_{2}$ , identical $X^1_{4}$ and all the possiblities of $X^1_{1}$
and $X^1_{3}$ .

So in order to build this structure I've been using input differences that goes from $(0000\;\;0000\;\;0000\;\;0000)_{hex}$ to $(FFFF\;\;0000\;\;FFFF\;\;0000)_{hex}$ and taking $plaintext_1$ in each pair from a large file of texts that I've collected from various books and then I would calculate $plaintext_2$ so that $\Delta plaintext=plaintext_1\oplus plaintext_2$ will be equal to one of the input differences in the previous range , so I should get a total of $2^{32}$ pairs as a result.

And in order to implement the second step of the attack I searched in the previously constructed pairset for pairs that their ciphertext difference statisfy $Y^{4'}_3=0$ and $Y^{4'}_4=0$ and they say in the paper I should get about $2^{31}$ pair that statisfy this condition so about half of the pairs will satisfy the condition.

But when I tried to implement these steps I get just about $10\%$ of the pairset that statisfied the previous condition , so is there anything I'm doing wrong with the way I'm implementing these two steps?

Comment: You're heading in the wrong direction if you consider plaintext to be "text". That's a classical term that's still in use for modern cryptography (just "message" is sometimes more clear, but generally we'd use e.g. "plaintext block" when it comes to indicating input blocks for block ciphers). Generally plaintext is just binary and you certainly would never use "text files" neither for input or for output to implement a plaintext attack.